# Only a few items in my class are being displayed?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nslog

I've been using Big Nerd Ranch's Objective-C guide and I'm having trouble displaying all the items in the class I created. For more reference it is the challenge in Chapter 17 about Stocks. I know there are other questions on this problem, but I've checked the corrected code for all the others and the problem still persist. For some reason only the Facebook cost is being displayed. Here's my work:
**StockHolding.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject
{
    float purchaseSharePrice;
    float currentSharePrice;
    int numberOfShares;
}

@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;

- (float)costInDollars;
- (float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

**StockHolding.m**

```
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation StockHolding

@synthesize purchaseSharePrice;
@synthesize currentSharePrice;
@synthesize numberOfShares;


-(float)costInDollars
{

    return numberOfShares*purchaseSharePrice;
}


-(float)valueInDollars
{

    return numberOfShares*currentSharePrice;
}


@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        StockHolding *apple, *google, *facebook = [[StockHolding alloc] init];

        [apple setNumberOfShares:43];
        [apple setCurrentSharePrice:738.96];
        [apple setPurchaseSharePrice:80.02];

        [google setNumberOfShares:12];
        [google setCurrentSharePrice:561.07];
        [google setPurchaseSharePrice:600.01];

        [facebook setNumberOfShares:5];
        [facebook setCurrentSharePrice:29.33];
        [facebook setPurchaseSharePrice:41.21];


         NSLog(@"%.2f.", [apple costInDollars]);
         NSLog(@"%.2f.", [google costInDollars]);
         NSLog(@"%.2f.", [facebook costInDollars]);



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
StockHolding *apple, *google, *facebook = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```

This line only allocated last `facebook` variable so `apple` and `google` are still `nil` when you add items to them.

Now, since Obj-C dynamically dispatches messages to objects, no error is raised when you try to add items to `nil` variables with `[google setNumberOfShares:12]` or when you invoke `[apple costInDollars]`.

Try with:

```
StockHolding *apple = [[StockHolding alloc] init], *google = [[StockHolding alloc] init], *facebook = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
```